# Avoid script loading using cURL

Tags: php, curl

How do I avoid script loading using cURL?

I'm loading some webpages using cURL, but some of them are badly written, and contain some scripts in the head that make the page very heavy and slow to load.

Considering that I don't need those scripts, is there a way to make cURL ignore completely all the scripts in the page I'm loading?

I know how to do it AFTER the load, but I need to do it before, in order to have a faster loading.

Note: I'm using PHP.

Comment: You cannot do that. Curl is simply a transfer agent. The are no filters like your asking for. Even if there were, it would still be impossible to filter the results without downloading them first.

Comment: cURL by default doesn't load scripts, if you perform a simple GET request, it will just get the result (HTML)

Comment: curl doesn't load any extra scripts.. doesn't even parse your result(ing html)